# Can we use 'local' in python as we can use 'local' in scheme?

Tags: python, scheme, racket

In scheme, we can use the function code : local, which is convenient to use.
so, is there any similar code in python ?

Comment: What part about `local` in Scheme are you hoping to learn how to emulate in Python? What have you tried?

Comment: If you define what `local` did, you're more likely to get an answer.  As it is now, you'll only get an answer from someone who knows both Python and Scheme.

Comment: local is designed to turn top level definitions into local definitions simply by surrounding them with the local construct. This is very convenient. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html?q=local#(form._((lib._racket/local..rkt)._local))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are asking if you can define functions within functions in python with similar behaviors as non nested functions.

The answer is, yes.

```
def some_function():

    def some_other_function():
        # code that does stuff
        pass

    # code that does stuff
    pass
```

These two functions will function identically, except the scope of `some_other_function` is within the scope of `some_function`.